# CocoaPods Failed to Lint A Podspec Due to Objective-C Generated Interface Header Not Found

Tags: objective-c, swift, cocoapods

When I tried to build a pod which some Swift files importing the project's Objective-C generated interface header( something likes `YourProductModuleName-Swift.h` ), it was always failed to build and said that the Objective-C generated interface header cannot be found.

How can I make the CocoaPod to correctly recognize the Objective-C generated interface header?